# Should Principal components be normalized before applying K means on them?

Tags: k-means, pca, normalization

I want to get the Principal components of a dataset and apply K mean clustering on them. Do I need to Normalized the PCA output before applying Kmeans on them ?

Comment: If the ranges of the numeric attributes differ by many orders of magnitude, then yes. You could also scale (divide each  by standard deviation in that column for instance)

Comment: Also you must scale the data before applying PCA. I hope you know that!

Answer (score 1):

No - There is no need to normalize after Principal Component Analysis (PCA) because each dimension is on the same scale.